# Frames per second Conceptual Details

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

i am  a newbie and trying to understand the concepts behind ffmpeg/video.

FPS means  frame per second , for example

```
25fps -> 25 frames captured in a second
```

From the display perpective

```
25 frames need to be displayed in a second.
```

correct me if i am wrong?

Now i  have written a simple video player in ffmpeg to display.  i read
frames by av_read_frame(),  if fps is 25, then does

```
 av_read_frame()
```

returns 25 frames per second? how can i relate it?

Answer (score 1):

Read and write operations don't have to honor the data rate of the stream in question. Instead, they happen without any delays as soon as possible. After all, if you transcode a file, you are typically not interested in doing it at 100% playback speed and more likely you are interested in having it completed quickly, as quick as reading, writing, encoding etc. allows.

Any source generating content is interested to properly time stamp it, attaching frame rate and individual timestamps, so that playback could reproduce the stream accurately, including relatively to other streams ("lipsync").

Any presentation system is interested in presenting data taking into consideration time stamps, adding delays and idle time if/when necessary, so that playback is accurate.

Everything else in between, including `av_read_frame`, only cares for not losing timings attached to data, and is executed without any delays (in case of `av_read_frame` returning you as many frames per second as it can).